# Binance.net wrapper Set TP and SL Problem c#

Tags: api, wrapper, binance

i use Binance.net wrapper , i can open position (Futures) , but i cant set tp and sl after open position

```
  var orderData = await binanceClient.UsdFuturesApi.Trading.PlaceOrderAsync(
            "BTCUSDT",
            OrderSide.Sell,
            FuturesOrderType.Limit,
            0.002m,
            ep,
            timeInForce: TimeInForce.GoodTillCanceled);
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

this library or Binance's api doesn't help you to create one order with TP/SL at one request. You should split it into 3 orders. For example to Buy/Long

```
var limitOrderResult = await _binanceClient.UsdFuturesApi.Trading.PlaceOrderAsync(
                                  symbol: "BTCUSDT",
                                  side: OrderSide.Buy,                                                                                                                                                        
                                  type: FuturesOrderType.Limit,
                                  quantity: 1,
                                  price: 0.002m,
                                  orderResponseType: OrderResponseType.Result,
                                  positionSide: PositionSide.Long,
                                  workingType: WorkingType.Mark,
                                  timeInForce: TimeInForce.GoodTillCanceled
                           );
```

Once the limitOrder is successful

```
     if (limitOrderResult.Success) {
        // take profit
        var tpOrderResult = await _binanceClient.UsdFuturesApi.Trading.PlaceOrderAsync(
                                    symbol: "BTCUSDT",
                                    side: OrderSide.Sell,
                                    type: FuturesOrderType.TakeProfitMarket,
                                    quantity: 1,
                                    stopPrice: 0.003m, // take profit price
                                    orderResponseType: OrderResponseType.Result,
                                    positionSide: PositionSide.Long,
                                    workingType: WorkingType.Mark,
                                    timeInForce: TimeInForce.GoodTillCanceled,
                                    closePosition: true // add this
                               );

        // stop loss
        var slOrderResultTask = _binanceClient.UsdFuturesApi.Trading.PlaceOrderAsync(
                             symbol: "BTCUSDT",
                             side: OrderSide.Sell,
                             type: FuturesOrderType.StopMarket,
                             quantity: 1,
                             stopPrice: 0.001, // stop loss price
                             orderResponseType: OrderResponseType.Result,
                             positionSide: PositionSide.Long,
                             workingType: WorkingType.Mark,
                             timeInForce: TimeInForce.GoodTillCanceled,
                             closePosition: true // add this
                         );
    
     }
```

**UPDATED (2022 April 23)**

You should add closePosition: true for place order TP & SL